# Pass temporary output between definitions / functions to use as input to next def

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, function

Lets say I have two functions:

```
class AnalyseDTM():

    def __init__(self):
        self.DTM = ('C:/Users/EH/QGis/Kvit_Tiny.tif')
        self.CreatePolygons()
        self.test()

    def CreatePolygons(self):

        translateFeatures = processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:translate", {
        'INPUT':self.DTM,
        'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:5110'),
        'NODATA':0,
        'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,
        'OPTIONS':'',
        'EXTRA':'',
        'DATA_TYPE':0,
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
        return 

    !HERE!

        RemoveSub0values = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator", {
        'EXPRESSION':'((\"OUTPUT@1\">0)*\"OUTPUT@1\") / ((\"OUTPUT@1\">0)*1 + (\"OUTPUT@1\"<=0)*0)',
        'LAYERS': translateFeatures['OUTPUT'],
        'CELLSIZE':None,
        'EXTENT':None,
        'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32633'),
        'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' })
```

I've removed about 20 other processing functions as the above should hopefully explains what I'm looking for. So you see I have a `def CreatePolygons`, which currently has two `processing.` functions in it. This works fine, however I'm wondering if where I have written `!HERE!` I can separate the two functions. For example I could call it `def test(self):`

Therefore, I'm wondering if I can pass the `'OUTPUT'` from `translateFeatures` and have it as the input for `RemoveSub0values` even when they are in separate `def` 's. I know that if I save it to file and have it in the `__init__` then yes, I can, as this is part of a large model I don't want to save multiple outputs to file every time.

I have a fully working class, but its extremely slow, and I therefore wanted to test if grouping processing algorithms would speed this up, but I therefore need to be able to pass temporary outputs between functions.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Can you show the full class definition (but only including the relevant methods, if it's large)?

Comment: @Tom I've updated the Q, hopefully easier to see what im looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a class like this: (Follow the highlighted numbers)

```
class AnalyseDTM():

    def __init__(self):
        self.DTM = ('C:/Users/EH/QGis/Kvit_Tiny.tif')
        output_lyr = self.CreatePolygons() ### (1) ###
        self.test(output_lyr) ### (2) ###

    def CreatePolygons(self):
        # only 'run' method gives you the reference of the output memory layer
        # use 'run' instead od 'runAndLoadResults' here. skipped some parameters
        translateFeatures = processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':self.DTM,
                                                              .....,
                                                              'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

        output = translateFeatures["OUTPUT"]

        # If adding the output to project is required, use the next line
        # QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output)

        return output  ### (3) ###


    def test(self, in_lyr): ### (4) ###
        ### (5) ###
        expression = '((\"{0}@1\">0)*\"{0}@1\") / ((\"{0}@1\">0)*1 + (\"{0}@1\"<=0)*0)'.format(in_lyr.name())
        processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator",
                                     {'EXPRESSION': expression, ### (6) ### 
                                      'LAYERS': in_lyr, ### (7) ###
                                      'CELLSIZE':None,
                                      'EXTENT':None,
                                      'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32633'),
                                      'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had tried, I had just forgotten to put the in_lyr in my def test()! Works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to print the content of translatefeatures['OUTPUT'], you'll see that it is a string. That string is a unique id of the layer created in the processing.

To work further on, you need to get hold of the layer.

```
    layer=QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(translatefeatures['OUTPUT'])
```

Then you can set up your next processing step using that layer.

You can see it in a bit more context here: https://github.com/sickel/altitudecorrector/blob/d5565/altitudecorrector.py#L314

(Funfact, but probably not useful here, if you go to Layer properties -> Variables, you'll find that id under Layer -> layer_id)

Hope this helps.